# Spring Redirect URL differs in browser

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am creating sample Spring MVC application.In this application i have one form when i submit the form i perform some action.

My problem is after the form submit url is changed for example i have url as `http://localhost:8080/SampleWeb/sample/user` this is for my form display  when i submit the form the url redirected to `http://localhost:8080/sample/user-by-name`

in my jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/sample/user">
   <table>
    <tr>
```

In my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    return "redirect:" + "SampleWeb/sample/user-by-name";
```

when i  change the redirect  url to  "/SampleWeb/sample/user-by-name"
it works in firefox but in chrome `http://localhost:8080/SampleWeb/SampleWeb/sample/user-by-name` it adds two times.

if i give `return "redirect:" + "/sample/user-by-name";` means  url will be `http://localhost:8080/sample/user-by-name`

I am new to the Spring mvc. Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first slash from this line `<form:form method="POST" action="sample/user-by-name">`

Comment: If i remove the slash means it says 404 and the url became `http://localhost:8080/SampleWeb/cafyne/sample/sample/user-by-name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:url var="myUrl" value="/sample/user-by-name"/>
<form:form method="POST" action="${myUrl}">
```

Comment: Please see my edited code after the form submit i redirected to another url in that url has only problem

Comment: It create problem when i deployed to my sercer

Answer (score 0):

Do not hard code the context path in your controller / jsp page. Mention context path in your JSP page as shown below. It worked for me.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sample/user-by-name">
```

Or

```
<form:form method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/sample/user-by-name">
```

Comment: This is not form submit problem. It is redirect url problem in spring. Please see my edited question